# RabbitMQ - Copy other queue's messages at queue creation

Tags: rabbitmq

I have multiple producers that publish to their specific (durable and limited) queues using the amq.direct exchange and particular routing key

```
Queues:
  producer.06
  producer.07
  ...

Routing keys:
  "producer.06" -> producer.06
  "producer.07" -> producer.07
  ...
```

I also have multiple consumers.  When they connect, they create their own (exclusive) queue and routing keys to receive all the messages from the queues that are of interest to them.  This way multiple consumers can get the same messages.

```
Queues:
  consumer.a
  consumer.b
  ...

Routing keys:
  "producer.06" -> consumer.a
  "producer.06" -> consumer.b
  "producer.07" -> consumer.b
  ...
```

I would like to populate the consumer's queue with a snapshot of messages of the relevant producer's queues, prior to binding the routing keys.   Loosing a few messages in the interval between the message copy and routing key binding is acceptable, and a better alternative than out-of-order messages for my application. The consumer should not remove messages from producer's queues (as they would be needed by other consumers).

Is there a way to achieve this? -copying a snapshot of a queue into another one- or does anyone has a suggestion on how to achieve this?

I am running RabbitMQ 3.8.4 on Erlang 23.0.2, and using Rabbit .Net client 6.0.0.0 for the consumers.